# Module dependency in Java-maven

Tags: java, maven

I'm new to Java. I have a maven project with two modules as follows:

```
project
 |_ module1
    |_ src
       |_ com.project.module1
          |_ Person.java
          |_ Controller.java
          |_ Application.java
          |_ MybatisMapper.java
    |_ pom.xml // pom of module1
 |_ module2
    |_ src
       |_ com.project.module2
          |_ Student.java // import Person.java
          |_ Controller.java
          |_ Application.java
          |_ MybatisMapper.java
    |_ pom.xml // pom of module2
|_ pom.xml // pom of project
```

Since module2 is dependent on module1, so I add dependence in pom.xml of module2 as:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Meanwhile I add this in pom.xml of module1:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <classifier>exec</classifier>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Otherwise there'll be an error during compiling that told me module2 cannot find package `com.project.module1`.

I wonder if this is what people usually do to relay on other modules in the same project. The executable jars of these two modules are `module1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar` and `module2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`. Can it be no`-exec` suffix in output of module1? Thanks a lot in advance.

pom.xml of the project:

```
    <groupId>com.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>module1</module>
        <module>module2</module>
    </modules>

   <properties>
        <output>${user.dir}/output/${project.artifactId}</output>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        ...
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <directory>${output}</directory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

build command:

> mvn -U clean package

Comment: Can you show the pom of the parent, and the command you're using to build?

Comment: I am not sure but I guess your error is to try to build a module that is both an executable and could be used a dependency. Each module should either be executable or a dependency, not both.